# Converting from svg to gif with ImageMagick do not preserve blurring

Tags: svg, gif, imagemagick-convert

When I run `convert -delay 100 img.svg img.gif`, blurring is not preserved (see below). How can I get a gif with the same appearance as the original image?

[Original image (left) and output (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXdWW.jpg)

Comment: Which SVG renderer are you using -- MSVG/XML, RSVG delegate, Inkscape -- listed in increasing order of quality. Add -verbose to your command to see which one. I suspect you are just using the ImageMagick internal MSVG/XML renderer. I suggest you install Inkscape and try again.

Comment: I'm using Inkscape.

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you use Inkscape itself  directly without ImageMagick to process the SVG file?

Comment: I made the SVG in Inkscape and the problem arises when I try to convert it to GIF.

Comment: What were your commands

Comment: I made the image in the Inkscape GUI (circles with 38% blur) and saved it as SVG. Then, I ran `convert -delay 100 img.svg img.gif`

Comment: Post your SVG input file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1leV4Fduy3Upk66ZouVgm0PrSHmeID23y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It opens for me in IM 7.0.10.57 (Inkscape installed) with blurring preserved, but a white background. Photoshop opens with transparency and blurring preserve, but say there is only 3 channels RGB. GIMP show both transparency and 4 channels RGBA and blurring preserved.

Comment: Does that happen after converting it to gif?

Comment: `@Osaldo Santos Baquero`  Yes, after converting to GIF. What is your ImageMagick version? Why are you using -delay 100 for a single frame image?

Comment: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23. I'm using the -delay with multiple frames. I just picked up one frame to illustrate the problem, without changing the command.

Comment: Your ImageMagick version is very old. The current ImageMagick version is 6.9.11.57. Perhaps you should try upgrading. Is your Inkscape version up-to-date? Also, have you tried not using ImageMagick and just use Inkscape to convert your SVG to GIF?

Comment: The problem persists with ImageMagick 7.0.10-57. How to convert to GIF with Inkscape?